# How to define Angular directive must be a child of a specific directive in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating directive to `AngularJS`, how to can I configure it must be child of directiveA?

Like this example:

```
<my-modal>
    <m-header>Header</m-header>
</my-modal>
```

`m-header` must be child of `my-modal`, if not, occur some exception

Comment: Have a look at [`require`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-). I'd be interested in the `^^` prefix.

Comment: what directive are you writing? `my-modal` or `m-header`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`require`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) parameter to effort the require of a parent directive like the code below.

```
app.directive('mHeader', function() {
  return {
    require: '^^myModal',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, myModalCtrl) {
      myModalCtrl.close();
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-header.html'
  };
});
```

Also, when using `require`, you can have access to the parent controllers, as you can see on `myModalCtrl`.

Comment: How it will check m-header must be child of my-modal

Comment: You should also explain your answer. Note that `require`, without a prefix, tries to locate the required controller on the current element, which doesn't satisfy Lai`s condition.

Comment: I was trying but it was blocked because you made an edit while I was edditing my post. I inadvertently erased part of the explanation. Anyways, thank you for your help :) appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is one workaround.
You can compare

```
 if(elem.parent()[0].localName= 'my-model') {

 }
```

With that u can know if its a direct child of that element